# Ionic: View list is not updating after data is increased in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic and am trying to add list of item dynamically.I have a local json file. I have a button in my default dash.html. When I click the button, it will reads the barcode and it checks the barcode is number available in the local json file. The data will be sent to the next page through app.js like the following code.

Controller.js

```
    $scope.scanBarcode = function() {
    $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(imageData) {
        // alert(imageData.text);  
        if(imageData.text.length!=0){
        console.log("Barcode Format -> " + imageData.format);
        console.log("Cancelled -> " + imageData.cancelled);
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({title: imageData.text});
        alertPopup.then(function(res) {
         $state.go('tablelist',{title: imageData.text}); 
        });
      }else{
        alert("Not captured properly.try again");
      }

    }, 
    function(error) {
        console.log("An error happened -> " + error);
    });
};
```

app.js

```
 .state('tablelist', {
  url: '/tablelist/:title',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tablelist.html',
      controller: 'TableCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

So I will get the data in $stateparams and I can compare and add it in the next page.

```
 .controller('TableCtrl', function($scope,$ionicPopup, $cordovaBarcodeScanner, $http, $stateParams) {
   $scope.users = []; //declare an empty array
   $scope.barData;
   $http.get("data/menulist.json").success(function(response){ 
   // alert($stateParams.title);  
   // if($stateParams.title==response.barcode){
    $scope.barData=$stateParams;  

    for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++){
      if($scope.barData.title==response[i].barcode){
        $scope.users.push(response[i]);
      }
    }
  });   

  $scope.scanBarcode = function() {
    $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(imageData) {
        if(imageData.text.length!=0){
        $http.get("data/menulist.json").success(function(response){ 
    for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++){
      if(imageData.text==response[i].barcode){
        $scope.users.push(response[i]);
        $scope.apply();
      }
    }
}); 
      }else{
        alert("Not captured properly.try again");
      }
    }, 
    function(error) {
        console.log("An error happened -> " + error);
    });
 };


  $scope.removeRow = function(user){
      $scope.users.splice( $scope.users.indexOf(user), 1 );
   };
 })
```

In the second page, again i have a button to read barcode and i want to add it in the same list. Here am not using sqlite.

This is my tablelist.html

```
 <ion-content>
 <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="scanBarcode()">Add Prduct</button>
 <ion-list>
 <div class="bs-component" ng-controller="TableCtrl">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Qty</th>
                                <th>Product</th>
                                <th>Image</th>
                                <th>Amount</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <div ng-app>
                            <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
                            <td>
  <select type="number" ng-model="quantity">
  <option selected="selected">1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  </select><br/>
  </td>
                                <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
                                <td><img class="td-img"  src="{{user.image}}"/></td>
                                <td>Rs: {{user.price*quantity}}
                                <input type="button" value="Remove" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="removeRow(user)"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                </div>
                        </tbody>
                    </table> 
                </div>

    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

I can see the data is adding to the list and it isnot updating when i give $scope.apply() inside or outside the loop.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Many people mentioned $scope.apply() will works. But it is not helping. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of $scope.users.apply(), Try : $scope.$apply();

Comment: @BalaAbhinav I tried both. But it is not working.

Comment: 1. Is there any error being thrown? 2. Are the users which you have got from the previous page displayed correctly?

Comment: @BalaAbhinav TypeError: $scope.apply is not a function

Comment: You have mis-spelled : It should be $scope.$apply() (Note the $ before apply). That is the correct syntax

Comment: @BalaAbhinav Yes I tried that also. Now it is showing 'Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress'

Comment: Okay, That is good. Why is there a ng-app in your div in the second page?

Comment: @BalaAbhinav I just want to display the price based on the quantity. So i used ng-app to do the dynamic multiplication.is that wrong? if it is wrong then can you tell me the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiplying the qty with price :

```
<div>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
        <td>
           <select type="number" ng-model="user.quantity">//Changed quantity to user level scope.
           <option selected="selected">1</option>
           <option>2</option>
           <option>3</option>
           </select><br/>
       </td>
       <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
       <td><img class="td-img"  src="{{user.image}}"/></td>
       <td ng-if="user.quantity">Rs: {{user.price*user.quantity}}//checking if quantity has been selected
       <input type="button" value="Remove" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="removeRow(user)"/>
       </td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

This should do it. ng-app is Angular's bootstrapping directive and should be used strictly for bootstrapping the app alone.

Comment: Iam getting the same error. 'Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress'

Comment: Can you open a plunkr(https://plnkr.co/) with your code and post a link to it. I will look into it..

Comment: I have not used that tool. I posted the important files index,dash,tablelist,controller and app.js. Please look at here https://plnkr.co/edit/k17rSaGSzKzzjVsZMxTi?p=preview.. Please tell me if you want any other info

Comment: Can you remove the ng-controller="TableCtrl" & Remove the <div> tag inside the <table> and try again. Your controller looks fine.. Issue is Probably something to do with the view.

Comment: If i remove the TableCtrl then how can i invoke a function from controller 'TableCtrl'

Comment: TableCtrl is already mapped to this view in your app.js, so no need to specify ng-controller which creates another scope which will cause issues

Comment: Thanks its working. Problem is not with controller. Even i removed $scope.$apply(); . Problem is in html div only. Thanks a lot for your time